# Firebase with Angular: how to count the number of nested entries in Firebase

Tags: angular, list, firebase, count

I have a strucure like this in firebase:
[image]

How can count the number of likes a particular movie has? Benn checking around and there is not much on this issue and besides it didnt help...Can someone take into the right direction? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean 'count the number of likes'. The movie in your question has 1 like. If someone else likes it, that number would be incremented to 2. etc etc. So there's really nothing to count based on your structure. Can you clarify?

Comment: well, maybe you're right. I wanted to make a ranking based on the likes each movie has.But this node is generated by a users comment. The author is the user, the movie, the number of likes etc. But yes, I uderstand, this node wont change, I need to rethink the structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general way is to count the childs but you might want to create a function

```
ref('reviews').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    let totalLikes = 0
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
       totalLikes += (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().likes.like) || 0
    });
    //do something with your total likes
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this snnioet you put is is a service constructor?

Comment: its correct, it counts, but my logic is all worng, thanks anyway :)

Comment: This code adds the total likes for *all movies in the reviews node*. `snapshot.forEach` iterates over each movie, gets the number of likes and then adds them all together. If there's 10 movies and each movie has 2 likes, the totalLikes result will be 20 which doesn't appear to be what the OP is after.